# Is .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 available for Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows, .net-3.5

Is .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 available for Windows 7 x64?

Answer (score 4):

It ships as part of Windows 7. You have to enable it though via:

`Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off:`

[image]